# Translation of "happy about one's share"

Tags: phrase-request, adjectives

What adjective phrase describes a person that is happy with what he has, in contrast to:

1. a person that envies what other people have;
2. a person that complains about what he doesn't have?

In Hebrew there is a phrase "שמח בחלקו" (literally: "happy in his/her share"). What is the parallel phrase in English?

Comment: "Content with his/her lot" would work.

Comment: I concur with @starsplusplus. *Lot* here means, etymologically, "what one is al*lot*ted", figuratively extended to one's situation in life, one's fortune or fate.

Comment: "Though poor the peasant's hut, his feast though small / He sees his little *lot* the *lot* of all" (Oliver Goldsmith)
http://www.bartleby.com/360/1/213.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is along the lines of what @starsplusplus said:

- "definition/translation" (my qualification)
- content with his lot (a little old fashion/formal)
- content with his lot in life (a little more complete)
- content with his portion (a common Jewish translation, perhaps a little old, perhaps literal)
- content with what he has  (a more conversational translation)
- content with what he has in life  (a more complete conversational translation)

I got all of these from various Jewish websites by doing google searches:

- `means שמח בחלקו`
- `English שמח בחלקו`
- `content שמח בחלקו`
- `happy שמח בחלקו`

With both the Jewish phrase as well as the translations, a common connotation is that **a person is not too happy/excited/emotional/attached with what they have in life.** Content describes this well.

The Jewish websites generally expand on the meaning in relation to the religious/spiritual associations of the phrase, but the above translations are the secular translations used in describing the phrase within the religious treatment.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few words you could use for this.

I would think the best might be satisfied, meaning:

> adj: "contented," or "pleased."

Another good definition might be "content," which, in a circular way, means the same thing as satisfied; the definition of "content" is:

> adj: "a state of satisfaction."

Even though both definitions reference each other, when you pick one, it will mean the same thing. Content(ed) usually means a person is happy, or at peace, with the current situation, while satisfied usually means a person feels they have adequately met, or completed, a requirement/desire.